# OpenGL Perspective Looks Off

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm using the following display code to draw the base of a bare-bones merry-go-round for a project:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0, 4.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -0.05);
glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
gluCylinder(obj, radius, radius, 0.1, 100, 1);
glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
gluPartialDisk(obj, 0, radius, 100, 1, 0, 90);
glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
gluPartialDisk(obj, 0, radius, 100, 1, 90, 90);
glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
gluPartialDisk(obj, 0, radius, 100, 1, 180, 90);
glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
gluPartialDisk(obj, 0, radius, 100, 1, 270, 90);

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Now, this more or less works fine. It produces this, which is about what I'm expecting (not to scale):

[image]

The issue here is that it just looks bizarre and unrealistic. The center should be in...well, the center, but is instead significantly further "down" the image produced. Rotating the scene confirms that the partial disks are, in fact, the same size and around the same origin. What could be causing this?

Comment: Since when is the center of a circle in perspective, in the center ?
Here is a good explanation: http://illustrationfixation.blogspot.co.at/2011/05/circles-in-perspective-part-one.html

Comment: I guess I should have said "somewhere near the center". Yes, perspective moves it "down" a little, but this just looks wrong.

Comment: Evidently I'm not allowed to edit - looking at that link made me realize that the image produced is backwards. The smaller half should be on "top".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is really the cause of your problem, but I got a strong hunch toward it: *You don't supply an aspect ratio that reflects your viewport's aspect ratio.*

In `gluPerspective` the second parameter takes the aspect of the viewport. Somewhere you have a call `glViewport(x,y,width,height)`. You should supply `gluPerspective` with the ratio of width and height, i.e.

```
gluPerspective(45.0, (float)width/(float)height, 3.0, 7.0);
```

Comment: I actually don't have any calls to glViewport - I'm not entirely sure what its purpose is. As for the aspect ratio, it's set to 1 but based on what you're telling me that's right because my viewport is actually 500x500 (I trimmed the rest out of the image).

Comment: @macamatic: The viewport tells OpenGL which rectangular area (in pixels) of the window shall the limits of the NDC volume (i.e. after projection) be mapped to. The default value is the full size of the window **at the moment** the OpenGL context was **bound to that window for the first time**. All subsequent changes of window geometry **do not** automatically reflect on the viewport. Relying on that default behavior is not very reliable, so it's highly recommended you set the viewport at the beginning of your display routine.

Answer (score 0):

If you had camera controls or could rotate it over time you might have a better idea of what was going on.

It looks a little like the cylinder partially obscures the red and yellow bits of the disc.

It seems unlikely but maybe there are further issues with depth testing or back face culling?

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); //not enabled by default on all OSes
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE); //just to be sure
glDisable(GL_BLEND); //for good measure
```

Be careful with the near/far values in the projection - they're pretty close and can easily clip stuff out you don't want. Then again, more than a magnitude of 10,000 apart and you'll hit depth fighting issues.

Comment: I have tried having it rotate over time and it basically looks how you'd expect it to from the above image. It rotates about the corners of the four partial disks. Removing the cylinder shows that it's not covering anything up. I tried your additions anyway but alas, they were no help. In fact, enabling depth testing causes the partial disks to be out of place for some unfathomable reason.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out to be embarrassingly simple. After looking at KoKuToru's link, It dawned on me that it was actually backwards - that is, the half of the circle that appears larger was on top when it should have been on bottom. With a little experimentation, I found that the culprit was in this line:

```
gluLookAt(0.0, 4.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

Specifically, the second parameter. It's positive, which indicates up, rather than down, which is what I really wanted. D'oh.